# Real Time Communication between two mobile phones

Tags: android, bluetooth, real-time, wifi

I am working on an Android app which requires that two nearby mobile phones (  < 5 ft) be able to communicate with negligible latency. The idea is to replicate touch co-ordinate information from one phone (the master) to the other phone (the slave) in real time. Latency will ruin the user-experience. What is a good way to achieve this? Bluetooth? 802.11 ? Is a wired link possible between the two phones with state-of-the-art phones available today?

Answer (score 0):

NFC is too short-range for what you're looking for. Perhaps you can use the local network (WiFi) where the master is the host and the other phone(s) are the slaves? That is most likely the route that I would choose.